# Can a class have a constructor, that has one argument: a reference to another instance of the same type, while not being a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So I have a class Widget that represents a tree of widgets, I want to have a constructor for widget that takes a reference to the parent widget. The class also has an explicitly deleted copy constructor. Does this mean that the constructor taking a reference to the parent widget is still considered a copy constructor? Does this mean unexpected things could happen if I were to store an instance of this class in a std::vector or some other container?

```
class Widget
{
public:

    Widget();
    Widget(Widget& parentWidget); // Is this a copy constructor?
    ~Widget();

    Widget(Widget&&) = delete;
    Widget& operator=(Widget&&) = delete;

    Widget(const Widget&) = delete;
    Widget& operator=(const Widget&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Yes, `Foo(Foo&)` is a copy constructor.

Comment: Why are you modifying the object you’re copying? That is against the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it [qualifies as a copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), even without the `const`.

I'm not sure if the standard containers will get confused by it, but your fellow programmers definitely will.

Use something other than a reference. `Widget(Widget *parentWidget);` would work.